# javascript jquery callback accumulates

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, accumulate

Issue:
Each time div.a is clicked, the number of callbacks when div.b is clicked,accumulates by 1.

```
var $=jQuery;
$(function(){
   $("div.a").click(function(){cbf(trgmsg);});
});
function trgmsg(){
   alert($.now());
}
function cbf(cb){
   $("div.b").click(function(){cb()});
}
```

Result:
click div.a once and click div.b => alert() pops-up;
if i click div.a again and click div.b => alert() pops-up twice consecutively;
if i click div.a another time and click div.b => alert() pops-up three times consecutively;
..and so on

I have No idea what the cause of the problem is or if its simply my misunderstanding/misuse of callback functions in JS. Any insights and/or advice will be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Well, you're calling cbf which add an event handler.

Comment: You mention the _undesired_ result, what is the desired result?

Comment: Thanks guys. After reading everyones responses, I think the issue was my level of understanding with jquery and event handling. My desired result was to only have one instance of the callback executed.

Answer (score 1):

Quickest fix for your code without a refactor is to just unbind and re-bind.

```
var $=jQuery;
$(function(){
   $("div.a").click(function(){cbf(trgmsg);});
});
function trgmsg(){
   alert($.now());
}
function cbf(cb){
   $("div.b").off('click').click(function(){cb()});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have now (refactored) looks like:

```
(function($){
  $(function(){
    function trgmsg(){
      alert($.now());
    }
    $('div.a').click(function(){
      // every time `div.a` is clicked a new click event is
      // attached to `div.b`.
      $('div.b').click(function(){ // maybe use `.one()` instead of `.click()`?
        cb();
      });
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

You may want to use `.one()` so after it binds it's only executed once. Or else you need to elaborate on what the *actual* goal is and see if that can be solves differently.

Comment: That will unbind the listener on `div.b` so it'll only work once. It's not a "if it's bound, just use the existing listener" solution.

Comment: WOW,just tried .one() and worked perfectly. My goal was to have a confirm dialogue (yes/no) and execute functions depending on the selection. I was having a problem bc everytime i selected a yes/no the # of executions that followed started duplicating. Thank you!

Comment: What happens on the 2nd alert dialog though?

Comment: i put the div.a click & alert to simplify my question as much as possible(so that ppl didnt have to read a bunch of code). In reality i have a function that calls a confirm dialogue, which waits for a response and then executes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to call the supplied function against `div.b`, when `div.a` is clicked, this might work for you

```
var $=jQuery;
$(function(){
   $("div.a").click(function(){cbf(trgmsg);});
});
function trgmsg(){
   alert($.now());
}
function cbf(cb){
   $("div.b")[0].apply(cb);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching multiple click events onto div.b.  So every time you click on div.a it is attaching another click event onto div.b so when div.b is clicked each of it's click events are fired.  You can try setting a flag that says a click has already been registered.

```
var $=jQuery;
var flag = 0;
$(function(){
   $("div.a").click(function(){cbf(trgmsg);});
});
function trgmsg(){
   alert($.now());
}
function cbf(cb){
   if (!flag) {
       flag = 1;
       $("div.b").click(function(){cb()});
   }
}
```

Although I'm not quite sure what your using this for so that may not be your desired functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your explanation was quite helpful in understanding the mechanincs of what im doing wrong. Is there a way to 'clear'/'reset' attached multiple events? or a way to count the # of events attached?

Comment: If you remove the if statement for the flag and turn the flag variable into a counter you can just flag++ every time instead. This would count every time the event was attached.  To remove them all you could just call $("div.b").off('click'); and that will remove all the click events for those elements.